# Unable to pull HTML from website

Tags: python, html, web, urllib

I'm pulling HTML from web sites, by sending headers to make the site think I'm just a user surfing the site, like so:

```
def page(goo):
    import fileinput
    import sys, heapq, array, urllib
    import BeautifulSoup
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    from urllib import FancyURLopener
    class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
        version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
    myopener = MyOpener()
    filehandle = myopener.open(goo)
    return filehandle.read()
page=page(WebSite)
```

This works perfectly with most websites, even Google and Wikipedia, but not with [Tmart.com](http://www.tmart.com/). Somehow, Tmart can see it's not a web browser, and returns an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you copy and paste the error or stack trace that would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: The website in question is using java script to set cookies and ignores requests without proper cookies.

Answer (score 6):

They might be detecting that you don't have a JavaScript interpreter? Hard to tell without seeing the error message you are receiving. There is one method that is guaranteed to work though. And that is directly driving a browser using Selenium Webdriver.

Selenium is normally used for functionally testing web sites. But works very well for scraping sites that use JavaScript as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.someurl.com')

html = browser.page_source
```

See all the methods available on browser here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
For this to work you will also need to have the chromedriver executable available: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: I ran <br> 'code' #!python27
def page(goo):
        from selenium import webdriver
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get(goo)
        html = browser.page_source
        return html.read()
  
page("tmrat.com")
 and i get <br> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Server\Downloads\scaner.py", line 9, in <module>
    page("tmrat.com")
  File "C:\Users\Server\Downloads\scaner.py", line 3, in page
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\Server\Downloads\selenium.py", line 806
    Hide details
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It looks like you didn't install selenium properly. Did you `pip install selenium`? Or just download a random part of it's code? It's an entire package. Delete the file `C:\Users\Server\Downloads\selenium.py` and install selenium properly. Also, browser.page_source is a string. It doesn't need to be `read()`.